# Who holds the record for most knockouts in professional boxing?

Tags: trivia, boxing

Which boxer has knocked out the most opponents in the boxing ring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some debate between Archie Moore and Billy Bird as the record holder for most KOs in a career. Bird landed 138 knockouts in his time, with 22 dealt to him. Moore KO'd 131 with only 7 knockouts dealt to himself. Ultimately it is accepted that Billy Bird holds this record with some unofficial fights also rumored to have taken place during his time.

[This](https://www.goliath.com/sports/10-boxing-records-that-will-probably-never-be-broken/)report discusses the official record but the argument that Moore's achievement could be considered greater based on opponents.